# Random Forest Underperforms Median on Training Set for Toy Regression Problem

Tags: regression, random-forest, median, training-error

I have found that random forests is failing on a toy regression problem. My prior impression of random forests is that it is very robust, so I expected that, on the training set, it should always outperform the median (predicting the median response for all inputs, which I take to be a notable benchmark for any regression problem). However, for some simple random data, I have found this to not be the case. Specifically, in R:

```
set.seed(77)
features = data.frame( a=rnorm(4200), b=rnorm(4200))
response = rnorm(4200)
mean( ( response - median(response))^2 )

rf.sim <- randomForest( x = features, y = response, maxnodes = 1, ntree=1000 )
mean( ( response - rf.sim$predicted)^2 )
```

setting `maxnodes = 1` helps more than anything so far, but it still underperforms slightly. I have read that random forests is resistant to overfitting, so maybe this partially explains the results.

What is the reason that random forest cannot beat the median here, and is there some tuning that would allow it to do so? Also, pursuant to that, what are the options for increasing overfitting in this situation?

Comment: You've set up a problem where there is no relationship between between the predictors and the outcome. The mean is the number that solves $\arg\min_m \sum (x - m)^2$. Given that the response variable is normally distributed, the sample median is a consistent estimator for the population mean, so you'd expect it to perform well in this setup. What is the problem with that?

Comment: @WillMarble: That's an answer. ;) (+1)

Comment: @WillMarble Yes, I'm aware that there is no relationship. I see you are correct about the mean; I think I had the median as I was accustomed to using the MAD over the MSE in the past. Swapping the mean for the median, the performance is now virtually identical. But the main issue is that, even though there is no relationship, I would expect that the model should still outperform the mean on the training set thanks to overfitting.